# Wildfly Maven Plugin error: deploy-artifact must specify the artifactId

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8

I've this dependency and artifact-deploy goal configuration in my POM file:

```
....
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
....
....
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    <configuration>
        <hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>
        <port>9991</port>
        <username>xxxx</username>
        <password>xxxx</password>
        <name>App.war</name>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        ....
        <execution>
            <id>deploy-artifact</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <name>postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar</name>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        ....
    </executions>
</plugin>
....
```

But if i run: *mvn wildfly:deploy-artifact* i recive this error message:

```
Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy-artifact (default-cli) on project Zeus: deploy-artifact must specify the artifactId -> [Help 1]
```

it seems that the configuration section is not read when the goal is executed! Where i wrong? Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined the configuration in an execution. When you execute a specific goal it uses the configuration defined on the plugin and not any of the executions defined.

You need to either move the configuration to the base plugin, execute the install phase or create a profile you can trigger.